# Converting Switch(true(), SELECTEDVALUE statement from PowerBI to Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a data model in *PowerBI* to automate a specific table, which utilizes the following code to dynamically switch between summing line items from my fact table and subtotals within the table I am creating:

```
AOIT Values = SWITCH(TRUE(),

SELECTEDVALUE(AOITable[Type]) = "Subtotal", AOITable[AOIT Subtotal],
SELECTEDVALUE(AOITable[Type]) = "ORR Subtotal", AOITable[AOIT Net ORR Subtotal],
AOITable[AOIT SumAmount])
```

**My problem is:** I need to load the same data model and functionality to be used in *Excel*, but the SELECTEDVALUE function is not yet supported in Excel. Is there a replacement for the SELECTEDVALUE statement above, which works perfectly in PowerBI, to be used in Excel?

Thanks!

I have tried using IF(HASONEVALUE combination to replace the SELECTEDVALUE function, but the IF(HASONEVALUE combo can only do T/F, not expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
AOIT Values =
VAR Selected_Type = IF ( HASONEVALUE ( AOITable[Type] ), VALUES ( AOITable[Type] ) )

RETURN
    SWITCH (
        Selected_Type,
        "Subtotal", [AOIT Subtotal],
        "ORR Subtotal", [AOIT Net ORR Subtotal],
        [AOIT SumAmount]
    )
```